# Angular 7 pdf display file from blob

Tags: c#, angular, filecontentresult

I'm returning a FileContentResult from my c# .NET API, in my angular 7 application I receive it as a blob with HttpClient and then use the following to open a new tab and try to display it.

```
this.myService.GetPdfBlob().subscribe(data => {
   var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
   window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
})
```

After doing this it opens up a new tab, but I see a huge json object's text where it starts with FileContents property and that value is a massive string that I imagine is the bytes of the pdf document. It looks kind of like this:

```
{"FileContents":"JVBERi0xLjUNJeLjz9MNCjI1IDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDg1NzU1L08gMjcvRSA3MzgzMy9OIDQvVCA4NTQxNS9IIFsgNDc5IDIyMl0+Pg1lbmRvYmoNICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgDQozOCAwIG9iag08PC9EZWNvZGVQYXJtczw8L0NvbHVtb...it keeps going..", "FileDownloadName":"MyBigFile.pdf"}
```

How do I make it display the actual pdf document and not this big JSON object of my FileContentResult? I eventually need to display multiple file types, but I'm just starting with pdf.

Comment: I think you'll be better off changing the api to return a MIME type of `application/pdf` with only the file bytes.

Comment: changing the c# contentType to 'application/pdf' did not change anything, it is still behaving the same giving me this object and displaying its string in a new tab

Comment: Since the problem is likely in the C# code you should post that

Comment: I got it working, I had to do some weird stuff in the angular code. There must be a better way, but this works. I'll answer the question with the code.

Answer (score 2):

I changed up my C# code slightly to return an object that has a bytes array byte[] called Bytes and a filename. I still had the problem until I did this in my angular code:

```
this.http.get(myUrl).subscribe(response => {
   var byteCharacters = atob(response.Bytes);
   var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
   var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/pdf"});
   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
})
```